# How to run the PHP script at scheduled time

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I need to run a php script at the scheduled time daily to update some fields in database and to send automated email. How I can do this?

Is it possible to write some service in XAMP server to run the script daily at scheduled time?  I have no idea how to update database and send email automatically at the scheduled time. Can any one share some ideas or concepts?

I am using PHP and MySQL running in Linux Server.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job to do it. Check out the examples on [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Examples).

The Cron Job should call a script using the `php` executable that runs the necessary task.

Answer (score 2):

Just create the script that does the required job, test it by hitting the URL in your browser once you are sure it works right. Copy the URL and add a [Cronjob](http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Then schedule this command to run at whatever time you want to run

```
php ABSOLUTE_URL_TO_SCRIPT >> logfile
```

The log file is optional. But it will give you a chance to see what happened.

For example if you want to run your script every 4 hours, and assuming your script is at http://localhost/work/scripty.php and assuming that your http root is /var/www,

you would run "crontab -e" in terminal and add the following line:

```
* */4 * * * php /var/www/work/scripty.php
```

If you need more information just comment I will update the answer.

Comment: That would run the job every 4 minutes, not hours. And why would you use lynx when you could simply run the script directly?

Comment: Thanks for correction and lynx is painless, because in php cli even if you just run the script the relative php includes would mess up unless you explicitly change the current directory to that of scripts. I want his script to run without any modification :)

Comment: If `include_path` is properly set, or you work with absolute paths (the full path to the current file is always in `__FILE__`) there should be no problems. Using lynx is unnecessary waste of resources; it includes lynx, the webserver and PHP. Running the script directly includes PHP.

Comment: both ways have their own pros and cons, I usually had many includes and didn't use absolute path. Also lynx is a very lean "text only" browser, so not many resources are hurt. However, i will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, We can create .sh file and can give a specific time to run that is called cron job.
SO should use this method just make a shell file and give a time period to it.
You should take a help with linux expert for that.

Use the following: [Cron Job](http://troy.jdmz.net/cron/)

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot run script by itself,since php doesn't have daemons like python !!
So you have to take OS help to invoke your custom script .

For example in linux :
(example.sh)
export USE_PHP=php
cd $SCRIPT_ROOTDIR
$USE_PHP -f cronfile.php service="checkdatabase"
(service is the parameter passed to your cronfile).

For setting up cron jobs ,have a look at this link 
 http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/